# ASP.NET MVC, @Html.EditorFor для свойства модели типа decimal и type="number"

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net

Допустим в модели есть поле типа decimal. Надо вывести его в input, пишем на вьюхе:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { type = "number", step = "0.01" } })
```

На клиенте формируется такой тег:

```
<input id="Price" name="Price" step="0.01" type="number" value="13,53" />
```

Вот из-за того, что в атрибуте value дробная часть разделена запятой, в браузере отображается пустое поле. И $("#Price").val() тоже возвращает 0.

Как это можно поправить? В теге html есть атрибут lang="ru". В web.config задано:

```
<globalization culture="ru-RU" uiCulture="ru" />
```

Интересно, что если в конфиге вставить:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en" />
```

то в браузере поле input заполняется числом с запятой в разделителе, но в других местах, при выводе через DisplayFor в разделителе дроби стоит точка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, решил обойти проблему, так как красиво решить не смог. Сделал следующее, в коде страницы @Html.EditorFor заменил на:

```
<input type="number" min="0" step="0.01" id="Price" name="Price" data-value="@Model.Price"  />
```

А в клиентских скриптах страницы добавил:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var price = $("#Price").data("value");
    $("#Price").val(price.replace(",", "."));
});
```

Вот такой вот костыль.